# Create a new drawing and set the page size

Tags: google-apps-script

I use Google Drawings to annotate screenshots. Currently, my workflow is to create a new Drawing, and then set the page size via **File** > **Page Setup** > **Custom**.

Using the Google Apps Script, is there a way to automate this workflow? For example, I could create a simple UI, with two text boxes and a button. I enter width and height in the text boxes and then click the button to create the new Drawing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Files in `DriveApp` from a blob source using the [`.createFile()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFile(BlobSource)) method.

One parameter in the blob object is MIME type, and [there is a `drawings` option](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types) you can use. It doesn't look like you can pass size data into the file, though.